# Cannot display data from a picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used a roulette where there several pictures which is randomly selected using JavaScript. I want to be able to display information about these pictures at the bottom of the page. I want information only about the current picture. I only managed to work with the slider. 
Should I store the picture in a database and then display them based on picture? I have no idea for the image details. Should i also post my JS.
Below is my code
`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header" style="">
        <h1>
            Roulette
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="roulette_container">
                <div class="roulette">
                    <img src="1.jpg" />
                    <img src="2.jpg" />
                    <img src="3.jpg" />
                    <img src="4.jpg" />
                    <img src="5.jpg" />
                    <img src="6.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn_container">
                <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary start"> START </button>
                    <button class="stop btn-large btn btn-warning"> STOP </button>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="right_container">
                <p class="demo_label"></p>
                <div class="speed_value param_label">
                    <span class="param_name">speed :</span> <span class="speed_param"></span>
                </div>
                <div id="speed"> </div>

                <div class="duration_value param_label">
                    <span class="param_name"></span>time     : <span class="duration_param"></span> sec
                </div>
                <div id="duration"> </div>

                <div class="data_value param_label">
                    <span class="data_name"></span>Exercise : <span class="data_param"></span> 
                </div>
                <div id="data"> </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


</div>

<script>
```

` 
I managed to do that

```
<script>
    function myFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6) {
        this.img1 = arg1;
        this.img2 = arg2;
        this.img2 = arg3;
        this.img2 = arg4;
        this.img2 = arg5;
        this.img2 = arg6;
    }

    var x = new myFunction("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
    if ( $('.roulette') = "img1.jpg") {
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = x.img1;

    }else{
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = x.img6;
    }
</script>
```

but i dont know how to call the current image.
the problem is here - **if ( $('.roulette') = "img1.jpg") {**

Answer (score 0):

> `$('.roulette') = "img1.jpg"` does not work, you cannot set the
>   roulette to the source of an image.

What you can do, instead, is **hide all the images to begin with**, then show the one 
that is currently active using

```
// hide images
$('.roulette img').hide();

function showImage(src) {
    $('.roulette').children('img[src="' + src + '"]').show();
}

// show the first image
showImage('1.jpg');
```